# Why are there no debug symbols in my vmlinux when using gdb with /proc/kcore?

Tags: gdb, linux-kernel

I've configure all `CONFIG_DEBUG_` related options to `y`,but when I try to debug the kernel,it says no debug symbols found:

```
gdb /usr/src/linux-2.6.32.9/vmlinux /proc/kcore

Reading symbols from /usr/src/linux-2.6.32.9/vmlinux...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

Why?

Comment: Could you verify that your `.config` file does contain the line `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y`?

Comment: Yes,I've verified that many times.

Comment: Are you compiling your own kernel, debugging a distro-packaged one?

Comment: Yes,I'm compiling my own kernel,but no debug symbols so far ...

Comment: Delete some .o file in your build tree and then type `make V=1` to get verbose output.  Does the call to gcc actually include the "-g" flag?

Comment: @Karmastan,I've verified with `make V=1`,and yes there is the `-g` flag

Comment: In GDB, what is the output of `(gdb) b fs/open.c:10`?

Comment: It's `Breakpoint 1 at 0xffffffff810d2814: file fs/open.c, line 10.`

Comment: Then it looks like you have functioning debugging support!

Comment: But when I try to view how `ptrace` is implemented(`l ptrace`),there's no such info `Function "ptrace" not defined`...

Comment: That could be because there is no function called `ptrace()` in the kernel.  If you're looking for the ptrace system call handler, it's called `sys_ptrace` and is defined in [kernel/ptrace.c](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.32.9/kernel/ptrace.c#L602). The macro `SYSCALL_DEFINE4(ptrace, ...)` actually defines the `sys_ptrace()` function after the preprocessor is done with it.

Comment: @compiler: I would like to remind you that you have an open bounty on this question.  Even if you don't award the bounty, you're still going to lose the reputation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my best guess so far:  I don't know, and it doesn't matter.

I don't know why GDB is printing the message "(no debugging symbols found)".  I've actually seen this when building my own kernels.   I configure a kernel to use debug symbols, but GDB still prints this message when it looks at the kernel image.  I never bothered to look into it, because my image can still be debugged fine.  Despite the message, GDB can still disassemble functions, add breakpoints, look up symbols, and single-step through functions.  I never noticed a lack of debugging functionality.  I'm guessing that the same thing is happening to you.

**Edit:**  Based on the your comments to the question, it looks like you were searching for the wrong symbol with your debugger.  System call handlers start with a prefix of `sys_`, but you can't tell from looking at the code.  The macro `SYSCALL_DEFINE4(ptrace, ...)` just ends up declaring the function as `asmlinkage long sys_ptrace(...)`, although it does some other crazy stuff if you have [ftrace](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt) enabled.

Answer (score 4):

make menuconfig->kernel hacking->[*]Kernel debugging->[*]Compile the kernel with debug info(CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO)

Comment: Didn't the OP say he did that already? "I've configure all CONFIG_DEBUG_ related options to y"

Answer (score 3):

It's also possible when you package your vmlinuz image, the debug symbols were stripped (when using make-kpkg to build deb package for linux kernel). So you have to use the built vmlinux file under your linux source tree to have those debug symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Add -g to the CFLAGS variable in the kernel Makefile

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I thought you would have to install the debuginfo package for your kernel to get symbols

Comment: No,I think I've already install this package:`CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y`