# How to view the addresses of kernel functions and system calls?

Tags: linux, kernel

is there any way to get dump of linux kernel. I want to view the addresses of kernel functions and system call.

I am trying to hack the system call table. I need to redirect every read and write through my lkm.

From linux 2.6 they don't export system call table. So, I am trying to find the address.

Comment: Is reading the source code an option?

Comment: It's Linux.  Of course reading the source is an option.  How helpful it'll be is another question... :)

Comment: i dont think so. I dont think system call table location is hard coded before compilation. It goes at address given by compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You need a debugging version of the `vmlinux` file, which is produced when compiling the kernel. Some distributions have that file in a debugging package for their kernel. See also [this](http://www.cs.wm.edu/~kearns/001lab.d/kernel_gdb.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5416406/507519).

Comment: Thanks for the links. It seems ubuntu has ddeb instead of debuginfo. Have you used any of them?