# Can't dissasemble function in Linux kdb

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, remote-debugging

I have kdb launched in my crashed Linux. And for some reason there is no `id` instruction in list of instructions (`?` command). So I can't disassemble any code.
But here is some [cheat-sheet](https://man.cx/kdb(1)), where we can see the `id` command in common list.

So how could I disassemble any known function in Linux kernel with kdb?

Comment: What architecture?  Serial or console?

Comment: @stark armv7l, 4.19 Linux kernel. How else can I check the version of kdb?

Comment: `id` is not one of the base commands listed here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.136/source/kernel/debug/kdb/kdb_main.c#L2795 but I think there are distro and arch specific extensions.

Comment: @stark picocom connection. So do you know some way to disass code in such debugger?

Comment: This may help:  https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/03/08/how-to-extract-and-disassmble-a-linux-kernel-image-vmlinuz/

Comment: Even easier:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/5416406/1216776